NullPointerException when accessing Context via GlobalSettingsPreferences in Android app after app is killed in background
I am encountering a NullPointerException in my Android application, specifically when attempting to access the Context via GlobalSettingsPreferences after the app has been killed in the background. This issue seems to occur mainly on Android OS 14.
In my code, I have a Logger class that is located in a separate module from the MainActivity. The Logger class initializes a File object using the Context obtained from GlobalSettingsPreferences. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:
Main Activity:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        GlobalSettingsPreferences.setContext(applicationContext)

Logger java class:
public Logger(Object clientInstance){
        if (clientInstance instanceof String) {
            clientInstanceName = clientInstance.toString();
        } else {
            clientInstanceName = clientInstance.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
        logFile = new File(GlobalSettingsPreferences.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + LOG_FILE_NAME);
    }


Most likely, the solution is to get rid of GlobalSettingsPreferences entirely, or at minimum have it be supplied to things like Logger using a dependency inversion framework (e.g., Dagger/Hilt for Java and Kotlin).
